# Call a function within a loop, and still wait for the transition end of the elements

Tags: javascript

I have a markup that contains five boxes, a next button, and a kind of navigation menu, which I can use to point to a specific box. The next button id used to perform a translation of the boxes, which works the way thought it was. But the indicators doesn't work properly.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Boxes -->
    <div class="box current-box">0</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <!-- End Boxes -->

    <button class="next_button">Next</button>

    <!-- Navigation  -->
    <div class="numbers-nav">
        <button class="number">0</button>
        <button class="number">1</button>
        <button class="number">2</button>
        <button class="number">3</button>
        <button class="number">4</button>
    </div>
    <!-- End Navigation  -->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
}

.numbers-nav{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.number{
    display: block;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var nextButton = document.querySelector('.next_button'); // The 'Next' button
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');  // Get all the yellow squares within the document
var boxesList = Array.from(boxes);  // Creates an array with the boxes
var numbersNav = document.querySelector('.numbers-nav');  // Get the container of all indicators (the numbers)
var numbers = Array.from(numbersNav.children);  // Creates an array with all the numbers itself

var transitionCompleted = true;  // Indicates that the transition is complete

function transitioned(e) {
    console.log('=== transition finished ===');
    transitionCompleted = true;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var currentBox = document.querySelector('.current-box');
    currentBox.style.transform = 'translateX(' + 100 + 'px)';

    // Prevent multiple click when transition
     boxesList.forEach(function (box, index) {
            box.addEventListener('transitionend', transitioned);
            box.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', transitioned);
            box.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', transitioned);
            box.addEventListener('MSTransitionEnd', transitioned);
     });

        // When the user clicks, translate the 'current-box' to 0px and then translate its next sibling 100px to the right
        nextButton.addEventListener('click', translateNext);
        // When the user clicks a number, repeat the translateNext function until 'current box' match the clicked number
     numbersNav.addEventListener('click', moveToSpecificBox);
});

function translateNext(e){
    console.log('Transition completed: ' + transitionCompleted);

    if(transitionCompleted == true){
        transitionCompleted = false;

        var currentBox = document.querySelector('.current-box');
        var nextBox = currentBox.nextElementSibling;

        currentBox.style.transform = 'translateX(' + 0 + 'px)';
        nextBox.style.transform = 'translateX(' + 100 + 'px)';

        currentBox.classList.remove('current-box');
        nextBox.classList.add('current-box');
    }
}

function moveToSpecificBox(e) {
    console.log('=== translating until an specific box ===');
    var targetNumber = e.target.closest('.number');

    // Discovers the position of the number inside the navigation box has been clicked
    var targetIndexNumber = numbers.findIndex(function(number){ 
        return number === targetNumber}
    );

    // Indicates the box that should have the 'current-box' class until the end of this code block.
    var boxTarget = boxesList[targetIndexNumber];

    while(!boxTarget.classList.contains('current-box')){
            translateNext();
    }
}
```

The idea is that the moment I click the **next** button, the box with the “current-box” class has a transformation, moving to its starting position, while the next box is moved 100px to the right, and becomes the "current box".

All boxes have their transition monitored to prevent functionality from triggering while elements are still moving. Therefore, while the transition is not finished, clicking in the **next** button doesn’t perform any action.

The navigation menu has indicators that are used to point to a specific box. When a number is clicked, it should repeat the functionality of the next button until the pointed box has the "current box" class.

If I click 2 as soon as the page loads, for example, the following should happen:

1st
Translate box 0 to 0px
Translate box 1 to 100px

Box 0 loses current-box class
box 1 receives the class "current-box"

2nd
Translate box 1 to 0px
Translate box 2 to 100px

Box 1 loses current-box class
box 2 receives the "current-box" class

Since box 2 is now the current one, the loop should stop. The following code snippet is responsible for doing that:

```
while(!boxTarget.classList.contains('current-box')){
    translateNext();
}
```

That code checks to see if the pointed box has the class "current box" and if it does not, the function "translateNext" will be executed.

The problem is that the code is generating an infinite loop.

I think this is happening because of the event listener that is monitoring the transition. The elements never get their transition finished, so the transitionedCompleted become permanently false.

It's possible to see what is happening adding an limit to the loop, like this one:

```
var stop = 0;
while(!boxTarget.classList.contains('current-box')){
If(stop >= 5){ break }
    translateNext();
stop++;
}
```

The translateNext function is executed only once, the transitionCompleted variable gets the false value, and its value is never changed again.

So, how can I call a function within a loop, while transition listener still works?

Comment: Can you shorten your question ? It's too broad

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you would want to use the `while` loop. Because, what is there to loop over?

In your code the `transitioned` function is fired whenever a transition is ended. So I would recommend that you call `translateNext` in that function. This way `translateNext` will only be called whenever a transition has finished and the next transition has to begin.

One of JavaScript's features is **events**. They enable you to trigger functions when certain events occur. It is a powerful feature and utilizing them can be a strong paradigm to work from.

```
function transitioned(e) {
    console.log('=== transition finished ===');
    transitionCompleted = true;
    translateNext();
}
```

And in your `translateNext` function you are selecting the `nextElementSibling` of the current element. You can use this to check if the current element is the last element. And make the function keep going until the last element has been reached. Add the following `if` statement.

```
var currentBox = document.querySelector('.current-box');
var nextBox = currentBox.nextElementSibling;
if (nextBox === null) {
    return;
}
```

This statement checks if the `nextElementSibling` is there will stop the function from running when it is not there.

I hope this will help.

Comment: If i call translateNext() whithin the transitioned function, once the page is loaded, it will call the translateNext function over and over again [codepen](https://codepen.io/fb16455/pen/abopWQE). Did that work for you?